# Can I mix character sets and collation in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is a field with the following setup possible in MySQL:

CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
COLLATE latin1_general_ci

I want searches in the field to be case insensitive but I don't want searches for a to match á.

For example:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field='abc';

Should find: ABC
Should find: abC
Should not find: ábc
Should not find: ÀBC

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: Looks like it can't be done. Well, guess that's it. I'm tired of MySQL's limitations, have to look into MSSQL and see if it can do better.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in mysql:

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE UPPER( field) = UPPER( 'string' );

Example:

```
mysql> select * from item;

+---------+------------+
| id_item | state_item |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | complete   |
|       2 | removed    |
|       3 | REMOVED    |
|       4 | REmoveD    |
+---------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT *  FROM item  WHERE UPPER( state_item ) = UPPER( 'removed' );
+---------+------------+
| id_item | state_item |
+---------+------------+
|       2 | removed    |
|       3 | REMOVED    |
|       4 | REmoveD    |
+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT *  FROM item  WHERE UPPER( state_item ) = UPPER( 'REMOVED' );
+---------+------------+
| id_item | state_item |
+---------+------------+
|       2 | removed    |
|       3 | REMOVED    |
|       4 | REmoveD    |
+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Is this what you need ?

---

If you were to use another rdbms - a CHECK constraint would be a choise but in MySQL they are not working. 
A workarount this is for you to create your own bussines logic flow using  **BEFORE INSERT** and **BEFORE UPDATE** *triggers* which either cause an error or set the field to its default value when the requirements of the data are not met.
**See example of such trigger :**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER bi BEFORE INSERT ON Tbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF(NEW.col1 != REGEXP '^[A-Z]+$') THEN
SET {you insert,updets etc here }
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '1'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT := 'check constraint on Tbl.col1 failed';'
    END IF;
END$$   
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: On first glance it looks like a workaround, but does it work on inserts as well? For example: Say I have "abc" in a table where each value must be unique. "ABC" should not be allowed to be inserted, while "ábc" should be allowed. Is there a way for this to work as well, using utf8mb4_bin collation?